# Turbo Assembler 16 bit compiler on Windows 10

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I just want to compile and debug my assembler projects easily and i downloaded Visual ASM programm for windows 10. Its runs and work on 32 bit TASM compiler, but i cant compile on 16 bit compiler. Before it i used dos-box for emulating dos to compile 16 bit commands. Now i want to know is  there possible way to compile some 16 bit commands on windows 10. Sorry for my english, thanks.

Comment: Not on 64-bit Windows, AFAIK.  16-bit asm has been obsolete for over 20 years; you could just write 64-bit or 32-bit code.

Comment: so its compile to virtual 16 bit or no?

Comment: programm calls ASM Visual   [link](https://gri-software.com/en/asmvisual/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can write and compile 16bit realmode programs on 64bit windows, but you cannot run them, because the embedded DOS emulator **NTVDM.EXE** is available only on 32bit Windows.
We have to install 3rd party emulator, e.g. DosBox.

```
D:>ver
DOSBox version 0.74-2. Reported DOS version 5.00
D:>tasm.exe
Turbo Assembler Version 2.01 Copyright (c) 1988, 1990 Borland International
Syntax:  TASM [options] source [,object], [,listing] [,xref]
```

Within DOSBox you can assemble, link, debug, execute with 16bit tools TASM.EXE, TLINK.EXE, TD.EXE.

Borland in 1993 released its 32bit compiler with built-in extender 32RTF which can run on 64bit Windows, your visual IDE probably uses that version:

```
C:\>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.15]
C:\>tasm.exe
Turbo Assembler  Version 4.0  Copyright (c) 1988, 1993 Borland International
Syntax:  TASM [options] source [,object] [,listing] [,xref]
```

However, you still cannot execute 16bit programs written in it outside of DOSBox.
You should abandon the realm of 16 bits, as @PeterCordes told you.

Comment: So its impossible to make my idle to compile some 16 bit com's on windows 10

Comment: It's possible to compile but not to run them directly on 64bit Windows.